# How to calculate correlation coefficients using sklearn CCA module?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to measure similarity between feature vectors using CCA module. I saw sklearn has a good CCA module available: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html

In different papers I reviewed, I saw that the way to measure similarity using CCA is to calculate the mean of the correlation coefficients, for example as done in this following notebook example: https://github.com/google/svcca/blob/1f3fbf19bd31bd9b76e728ef75842aa1d9a4cd2b/tutorials/001_Introduction.ipynb

How to calculate the correlation coefficients (as shown in the notebook) using sklearn CCA module?

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA
import numpy as np

U = np.random.random_sample(500).reshape(100,5)
V = np.random.random_sample(500).reshape(100,5)

cca = CCA(n_components=1)
cca.fit(U, V)

cca.coef_.shape                   # (5,5)

U_c, V_c = cca.transform(U, V)

U_c.shape                         # (100,1)
V_c.shape                         # (100,1)
```

This is an example of the sklearn CCA module, however I have no idea how to retrieve correlation coefficients from it.

Comment: implementation will go here eventually once I get to it: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils/issues/10 I think one can use the cca directions (i.e. linear combination leared `a, b` or `w1, w2` of size `[n, p1], [n, p2]`) as following for the kth correlation: `correlation_k = pearson_correlation(a_k, b_k)`. Probably obtainable via some matrix multiplication like `a^T b` or something. Or using some singular value thing...idk if scipy gives us that. Btw, I've noticed that scipy is not very fast so idk if it's actually practically useful besides for debugging.

Comment: have you tried to use the numpy functio numpy.corrcoef  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/referencehttps://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Comment: @t2solve link is broken.

Comment: sorry once again; https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Comment: Did you check the source code? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/cross_decomposition/_pls.py#L801

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In reference to the [notebook](https://github.com/google/svcca/blob/1f3fbf19bd31bd9b76e728ef75842aa1d9a4cd2b/tutorials/001_Introduction.ipynb) you provided which is a supporting artefact to and implements ideas from the following two papers

1. ["SVCCA: Singular Vector Canonical Correlation Analysis for Deep Learning Dynamics and Interpretability"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05806). Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS) 2017
2. ["Insights on Representational Similarity in Deep Neural Networks with Canonical Correlation"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05759). Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS) 2018

The authors there calculate 50 = min(A_fake neurons, B_fake neurons) components and plot the correlations between the transformed vectors of each component (i.e. 50).

With the help of the below code, using [`sklearn CCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html), I am trying to reproduce their *Toy Example*. As we'll see the correlation plots match. The sanity check they used in the notebook came very handy - it passed seamlessly with this code as well.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import CCA

# rows contain the number of samples for CCA and the number of rvs goes in columns
X = np.random.randn(2000, 100)
Y = np.random.randn(2000, 50)

# num of components
n_comps = min(X.shape[1], Y.shape[1])
cca = CCA(n_components=n_comps)
cca.fit(X, Y)
X_c, Y_c = cca.transform(X, Y)

# calculate and plot the correlations of all components
corrs = [np.corrcoef(X_c[:, i], Y_c[:, i])[0, 1] for i in range(n_comps)]    
plt.plot(corrs)
plt.xlabel('cca_idx')
plt.ylabel('cca_corr')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

For the sanity check, replace the Y data matrix by a scaled invertible transform of X and rerun the code.

```
Y = np.dot(X, np.random.randn(100, 100))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how to extend this to multi-view CCA(MCCA) with more than 2 views, for example, 3? where you transform 3 variables: X_c, Y_c, Z_c = mcca.transform(X, Y, Z), How to calculate their correlations? is it possible?